# Query to Determine Data with Characters and Numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and am looking to query a table where the PORTAL_OBJNAME starts with 'NCC_S' and then is immediately followed by a number.  So for example 'NCC_S23434FJK0' should be displayed.  I used the query below but it returns nothing which is not correct.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM PSPRSMDEFN 
WHERE PORTAL_REFTYPE = 'C'
AND PORTAL_OBJNAME LIKE 'NCC_S%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: You need [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REGEXP_LIKE function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

```
WHERE PORTAL_REFTYPE = 'C'
AND regexp_like( PORTAL_OBJNAME, '^NCC_S[0-9]+' )
```

Comment: that worked!  thanks!  I'll accept the answer in a few minutes

Comment: what if I wanted to do the opposite and find anything that was NOT 'NCC_S' followed by a number?

Comment: do I just add 'NOT' in front of regexp_like?